# how to iterate through this array of objects in javascrip

Tags: javascript, loops, parameter-passing, xhtml

```
{"airplane_models":[{"name":"A770","max_passenger":230},{"name":"A342","max_passenger":130},{"name":"A341","max_passenger":234},{"name":"B345","max_passenger":21}]}
```

In the text above i provide what was given in the xhttp response. Output was done via

```
window.alert(this.responseText)
```

then this gets passed to the function:

```
displayModels(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
```

then i have a function that is supposed to add insights of this array to the table:

```
/**
 * Updates the DOM tree in order to display users.
 *
 * @param {Array.<{name: String, max_passengers: Number}>} airplane_models
 */
function displayModels(airplane_models) {
    let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
    clearElementChildren(tableBody);
    airplane_models.forEach(model => {
        for(let key in model)
        {
            window.alert(key)
            tableBody.appendChild(createTableRow(key));
        }
    })
}
```

But this does not append the table, even the `window.alert(key)` never outputs anything.

I tried to modify A code in a various way, firstly by changing `@param`

```
* @param {{name: String, max_passengers: Number}[]} airplane_models
```

but it gives me basically the same output. I also tried modyfing the for loop:

```
Object.keys(airplane_models).forEach(model => {
    window.alert(model.name)
    tableBody.appendChild(createTableRow(model.name));
})
```

Exactly the same result, no output at `window.alert(model.name)`

Comment: You have to use `JSON.parse()this.responseText)` to convert the JSON to an object.

Comment: @Barmar just editted, I was already doing it

Comment: You're not accessing the `.airplane_models` property of the object. `displayModels(JSON.parse(this.responseText).airplane_models)`

Comment: @Barmar okay thank you, but now it returns undefined to all fields

Comment: Time for you to get into the browser's debugger and figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Do you see the expected array if you do `console.log(airplane_models)`?